# Need to port 2D Arrays to Bash 3.2.39 from 4.1.9

Tags: arrays, bash

I have written a script that uses many two-dimensional arrays declared by using:

```
declare -A array_name
```

I've since added a lot of code (about 800 lines) that uses these arrays. The issue is that I have written and tested this in Bash 4.2.9(1), and now I need to have this code compatible with Bash 3.2.39(1) which clearly doesn't support that declaration (I get errors up the wazoo).

Here are the errors I'm getting if you're interested:

```
./script.sh: line 1072: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
```

For example I would set the arrays in this fashion:

```
array_name[1,4]="pls help"
```

And then output or access them in this fashion:

```
printf "%s" "${array_name[1,4]}"
```

Of course with a much bigger array with sizes that range from 1x20 to 70x15 with more useful information stored in them.

Is there any way to do this without changing much of Bash 4.X's functionality to access and store things in arrays?

Comment: If your code is 800+ lines and you're using data types like associative arrays... then you shouldn't program in Bash! Perl, Python, Ruby, etc. are your friends in this case.

Comment: agreed... i hate bash more than 200 lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash does not really have 2D arrays.  What you're using are 'associative arrays' where the subscript is a string (but your strings happen to contain commas and look a bit like two subscripts).  Associative arrays are wonderful but not easily simulated.  It is sufficiently hard that I would not try.

You could (sort of, extremely clunkily) do it with two arrays: an array to hold the '2D' subscripts as values each with an index number, and an ordinary integer indexed array that holds the real values.  You'd need a function to add a new entry and another to lookup an entry.  And you'd then have horrendous subscript expressions:

```
${array1[$(lookup "$subscript1")]}
```

or thereabouts.  But that is horrid and requires an O(N) linear search to find the subscripts, etc.

You'd probably find it a lot easier to code in a language that has native support for associative arrays (Awk), hashes (Perl) or dictionaries (Python), etc.  And you'd be able to code to the same other language on both systems.

Or simply get Bash 4.x installed on the other machines — that might be simpler still.  It needn't (probably shouldn't) be installed over the standard Bash 3.x; you could install `/bin/bash4` and use that in the shebang line `#!/bin/bash4` — or install it in `/usr/local/bin` or whereever else you use to install software.

[Wittgenstein](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Ludwig_Wittgenstein) said "The limits of my language mean the limits of my world."  In this context, the absence of associative arrays in a language (Bash 3.x) are a distinct limitation on the world of programs that you can write.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight! I had no idea that's how associative arrays worked. I'm thinking of using a one dimensional array but with two variables as one index like array_name[$(( $(( $width * $q )) + $s ))"] where q would have been the row index and s would have been the column index since the other code already works as needed.

Comment: Well, if there's a good mapping like that, then use it.  However, you can do the arithmetic with one pair of `$((…))`:  `${array_name[$(( $width * $q + $s ))]}`.  If you're careful, you can get both single quotes and double quotes in that expression too!

Comment: Wow, that makes the arithmetic a lot cleaner than what I have right now! I'm still pretty new to bash, so I'm definitely walking away with some good information from all you help, thank you so much! _runs off to fix code_